# Predefined variable ArtifactStagingDirectory location relative to each build or each pipeline?

Tags: azure-pipelines

I see in the docs that this folder $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) is purged on each build, but what about when another build happens for a different pipeline?
Eg.  Say I have 3-4 different build / release pipelines
If I do a build for project 1 that goes to its first stage, but before I let that release go to its next stage, a build is kicked off for project 2.

Does each build pipeline get its own area where artifacts are dropped? or is this common between all of your pipelines?

from the docs:

> This variable is **agent-scoped**, and can be used as an environment
> variable in a script and as a parameter in a build task, but not as
> part of the build number or as a version control tag.

So now I guess the question is - does each pipeline get a different build agent?

Also from the docs:

> Pipeline artifacts are tied to the pipeline that they're created in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Predefined variable ArtifactStagingDirectory location relative to each build or each pipeline?

The answer is that the `ArtifactStagingDirectory` location relative to each **pipeline**.

According to the document [Use predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml):

> Variables give you a convenient way to get key bits of data into
> various parts of **your pipeline**.
>
> Does each build pipeline get its own area where artifacts are dropped?
> or is this common between all of your pipelines?

Yes, each build pipeline get its own area where artifacts are dropped. It would be better to use a self-hosted agent to illustrate this question. When we use the self-hosted agent to build a new pipeline, it will allocate a new separate **work folder** for this pipeline. By default when installing TFS Agent you can choose the default for the work folder _work and normally this goes under the root directory of where you install the agent. So in this example they had the agent work folder at:

```
C:\<YourPrivateAgentName>\_work
```

When we open the working folder, we can see a lot of folders with numbers, each folder with numbers corresponds to a build pipeline：

[image]

Further open the numbered folder, we will see some fixed folders, and artifacts will be placed in the `a` folder.

> So now I guess the question is - does each pipeline get a different
> build agent?

When you use the self-hosted agent, it depends on how many agents are available in your agent pool, if you have multiple agents in your pool, each pipeline will randomly select an agent to complete the build task:

`Project Settings`->`Agent pools`:

[image]

So, if you have only one agent in your pool, when your pipeline uses the same agent pool, it will get the same agent. When there are multiple agents in your agent pool, then the agent situation obtained by pipeline depends on the respective situation of the agents in the pool.

When you are using a hosted agent, MS will randomly assign a new machine as an agent every time, so whether each pipeline gets a different agent depends on whether the pipeline is random to the same machine.